# Input Streams.read() How does it work exactly?

Tags: java, stream, inputstream

I'm having the following code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

 FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("c:/data.txt");

 FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("c:/result.txt");

 while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
  int data = inputStream.read(); 
  outputStream.write(data); 
 }

 inputStream.close(); 
 outputStream.close();
}
```

I dont get my head around  the following line: 
`int data = inputStream.read();`

Get the bytes of the file c:/data.txt, read byte by byte, and then get concatenated automatically within the variable data or does `inputStream.read()` read the file `c:/data.txt` all at once and assign everything to the data variable?

Comment: From javadoc: "Reads the next byte of data from the input stream." So while there are bytes remaining, `data` = the next byte

Comment: It reads the input file byte by byte, assigns it to `data`, then writes it to the output.

Comment: All the information you need to answer this question for yourself is in the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) for `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`.  The `read` call reads one byte and returns it as an `int`.

Comment: I should point out that 1) this is a horrible inefficient way to copy a file, and 2) using the `available()` method for almost anything (including this) is a bad idea.  A better idea is to *test* the value returned by the `read` call.

Comment: So the different byte values get kind of concatinated within the data variable?

Comment: Nothing gets concatenated. Why do you think that? A variable of type `int` holds exactly one number at a time. Do you understand the concept of a loop? The body of the `while` loop is executed multiple times, as much as there are bytes in the source file. Since this implies that `outputStream.write(data);` also is executed once for each byte, the bytes will be concatenated in the target file.

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example, may be it feels better to understand this way.

Comment: Data is just an integer, only 4 bytes. It really holds just one byte in this loop. You read into data, then you immediately write this same value. Then the loop continues, and you keep repeating this. At no time does data contain more than. Just one byte of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html):

A `FileInputStream` obtains input bytes from a file in a file system. 
`FileInputStream` is meant for **reading streams of raw bytes such as image data**. 
For reading *streams of characters*, consider using `FileReader`

> **Question:** Get the bytes of the file `c:/data.txt`, *read byte by byte*, and then get concatenated automatically within the variable
>   data or does `inputStream.read()` read the file `c:/data.txt` *all at
>   once* and assign everything to the data variable?

To Answer this lets take example:

```
try {
  FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("c:/data.txt");
  int i = fin.read();
  System.out.print((char) i);
  fin.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

Before running the above program a `data.txt` file was created with text: `Welcome to Stackoverflow`.

> After the execution of above program the console prints single
>   character from the file which is `87` (in byte form), clearly
>   indicating that `FileInputStream#read` is used to read the byte of
>   data from the input stream.

---

So , `FileInputStream` reads data `byte` by `byte`.